# VBA: How to make an IF statement on a DateDiff function

Tags: vba, excel, datediff

In a VBA project i'm working on, I need to count the number of lines where the difference between two dates is inferior to X hours.

My idea was to go through all the lines and check for each line, like this:

```
Dim count as Integer
if DateDiff("h", date1, date2) < 24 then
    count = count + 1
End If
```

The problem is that I get an incompatibility type error (execution error 13).

Is it possible to make IF statements on a DateDiff function? Or is it maybe possible to make a filter with DateDiff as the condition?

Thanks for the help and sorry for my poor english as it's not my main language!

Comment: I don't get an error.  What are the dates when the error happens?  And how are date1 and date2 declared?

Comment: The dates are '14/10/2015  19:00:00' and '14/10/2015  16:28:43'
Writing this reponse, I think I might have figured out the error: there are two spaces between the date and the time, can it be the error?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it like this without any errors.

```
Dim date1 As Date
Dim date2 As Date

date1 = "14/10/2015 19:00:00"
date2 = "14/10/2015 16:28:43"

If DateDiff("h", date1, date2) < 24 Then
    count = count + 1
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The VBA conversion function `CDate` can apply a little of the overhead you constantly pay for to correct the dates. With that said, it is best to correct the data to begin with and not rely upon error controlled conversion functions.

```
Dim date1 As Date, date2 As Date, n As Long

date1 = CDate("14/10/2015  19:00:00")
date2 = CDate("14/10/2015  16:28:43")
Debug.Print date1 & " to " & date2

If IsDate(date1) And IsDate(date2) Then
    If DateDiff("h", date1, date2) < 24 Then
        n = n + 1
    End If
    'alternate
    If date2 - date1 < 1 Then
        n = n + 1
    End If
End If
```

Given that 24 hours is a day and a day is **1**, simple subtraction should be sufficient for this base comparison.

Your DMY format may cause problems with the EN-US-centric VBA in date conversion. If an ambiguous date string is found (e.g. "11/10/2015  16:28:43") you may find that you are interpreting it as MDY.